# How to make a Call Invitation when app is killed in Android?

Tags: android, agora.io, videocall, android-connectionservice

I am using Agora sdk to integrate Video Call functionality. I have successfully integrate Call Invitation part where other user can accept or reject their call. But this invitation only works when the app is running. How do I make it work when app is killed?
I searched online and get to know about ConnectionService but don't how to use it on my app.

Answer (score 0):

To implement Call Invitation you need to use Agora RTM SDK along with `ConnectionService`. You can read more about it here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/faq/call_invite_notification